# Compare file line count with a file content in all sub directories using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I can compare the count of lines in a file with content of another file
for example:
file1 line count is 10
file2 contains 12
then not equal

using the following script

```
@ECHO off
rem using linecount and putfileinvar to compare  count and datafile
Set _File=testfile.txt
Set /a _Lines=0
For /f %%j in ('Type %_File%^|Find "" /v /c') Do Set /a _Lines=%%j
set /p myvar= < filecount.tmp
rem echo %myvar%%_lines%
IF %myvar% == %_lines% (ECHO eq )  ELSE (ECHO neq )
```

Now I want do do this for a whole directory and its sub directories where every sub directory contains two files
    datafile and its count in a sperate file

I want to compare the number of lines of the datafile with the count file

Comment: `... every sub directory contains two files datafile and its count in a sperate file ...` Is there any way to know which one is the data and which is the count?

Comment: Is there a file in each folder with the count inside?  Please explain a little further.

Comment: Can't your batch file call an executable that will do the job instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
:: list foleders in the root directory and store them in list file
dir /b /o:n /ad > dirlist.txt
:: for each directory in list
     FOR /F "tokens=*" %%v in (dirlist.txt) do (

     ::store dat file names in each directory in a temp file
     ::Log inside each folder
     cd  %%v
     ::list dat files in file.txt
     dir  *.dat /b /o:n  > file.txt
     ::for each file stored in file.txt
     FOR /F "tokens=*" %%m in (file.txt) do (
     ::count lines inside dat file
     findstr /R /N "^" %%m | find /C ":"  > save_temp_count.txt 
     ::Get the contents of the temp file and save it to the %mycount% variable
     set /a mycount<=save_temp_count.txt
     )
     ::delete temp files
     del file.txt
     ::Get all files tmp files
     dir *.tmp /b /o:n  > file.txt
     ::get file names in file.txt
     for /F "tokens=*" %%j in (file.txt) do ( 
         set /a fcount=<%%j
               )

     if  %fcount% == %mycount% (echo 1eq )  else (echo neq & echo %%v >> ../result.txt)
     ::delete temp files
     del file.txt
     del save_temp_count.txt
     ::go up back to parent folder
     cd ..

        )
```

copy this and paste it in the root directory where your folders exist , note that this script will not handle unexpected scenarioes , like:

found more than 2 files in a folder.
extensions are different from expected ( dat , tmp ).
tmp files dont contain an integer.

hope this helps.